# Why did the variable not update after a for loop in C++?

Tags: c++

As someone new to C++, why does the `int i` not print a value after the loop? Note: we are looping through a self-created array of length 5.

```
int i = 0;
std::cout << i << "\n" // for testing: prints 0 

for (CArray<int>::Iter it(arr); it; ++it)
{
    if (*it != eq[i])
        return 1;
    ++i
    std::cout << i << "\n"; // for testing: prints 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
}

std::cout << i << "\n"; // why does this not print anything?
```

This is returned on the console:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: This doesn't provide enough code to run, but it's probably because of the `return` inside the for loop.

Comment: Yep, just tested it and that seems like the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
std::cout << i << "\n" // for testing: prints 0 

for (CArray<int>::Iter it(arr); it; ++it)
{
    if (*it != eq[i]) {
        std::cout << "error" << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    ++i
    std::cout << i << "\n"; // for testing: prints 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
}

std::cout << i << "\n"; // why does this not print anything?
```

This is returned on the console:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
error
```

So, the issue was with the looping and not the variable.